# MySQL value 0 or 1 if row exists in other table or not

Tags: mysql, sql, return, row, exists

Searched StackOverflow for a while, and I did't find the an answer I can use, so here is my question:

I have a table called "uploads" where I store information about all uploaded images on the site.

Then I have another table called "gallery". If an entry in "uploads" (col id) exists in "gallery" (col file), the uploaded file is unlocked to the gallery, if an entry in "uploads" is not in "gallery" it's locked.

If I use a normal JOIN, all entries in "uploads" that are not in the "gallery" table are missing.

I want something similar to this:

```
SELECT [some other properties], (IF entry exists in gallery then 1 else 0) AS unlocked FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a `left join`

```
SELECT (g.file is not null) as unlocked
FROM uploads u
left join gallery g on g.file = u.id
```

Comment: This is the Query I made out of your Answer:

`SELECT u.id, u.original, u.filename, u.time, u.views, us.email, CASE WHEN g.file IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS unlocked
    FROM uploads u, users us LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.file=u.id 
    WHERE u.artist=us.id`

But I get the following error: `Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'`

Did I do something wrong with the other non-Left-Join ?

Comment: Ok, I did a LEFT JOIN on the other table too, now it works, thanks!

Comment: As a note, the `case` is unnecessary.  You can just do `(g.file is not null) as unlocked`.